# Text is shoved up 1px when using line-height: 0

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts

The font never actually changes on the text in the span, but the font on its parent (the paragraph) does. `line-height: 0;` is applied to the span.

See the gif below:
[image]
See the below codepen to test it out in browser

https://codepen.io/BelfordZ/pen/ZxvKxe

The answer to this questions should:

1. Explain why the text moves upward when the font for the text never actually changes.
2. Provide a solution that would work no matter which font is used and leaves the styles on the span unchanged. (ie: `line-height: 0;` must remain). If this is not possible, please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `line-height:0;`. You can prove that my commenting out that line to, and just change the settings on the paragraph.

You kind of answer your own question: "The font never actually changes on the text in the span, **but the font on its parent (the paragraph) does**."

- Explain why the text moves upward when the font for the text never actually changes.

When you haven't set a font on the p-element, it is inherited from the previous elements in the hierarchy, and if nothing is found there, the default font the browser has. In my case it is Times New Roman, 16px.

Since your change the font on the paragraph from the default font to something you have specified, the browser uses the characteristics of the default font when it places where the span-element goes (from the point of the browser, the span tag is one character) You can see this effect even more of you set a large font-size on the paragraph and a small one on the span: `p {font-size:30px;} span{font-size:10px;}`

`line-height:0;` on the span-element doesn't give you a line-height of 0, since  span is an inline-element: Try to add 'display:block;' on the span to see what I mean. There is no difference between a line-height of 0 or 1 on the span (but if you change it to a block-element there is a big difference).

- Provide a solution that would work no matter which font is used and preserves `line-height: 0`

You can set `line-height: 0` on the p-element, to remove the effect of the font and then set `line-height: 1` on the span-element. (I don't think you really want line-height:0;)

```
p {
  line-height: 0;
}

span {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @some. This is a great answer, though I would really love to see a solution that doesn't modify the span element's styles. Ill update my question to clarify the intent is to preserve all the styles on the span. If it is not possible, an explanation of why would be ideal.

Comment: Also, do you have any recommendations for better titles to the question?

Comment: @Belfordz If you don't want the default value (that will vary between platforms, browsers, and users) then you have to set the value that you would like. A better title? something like "text in span moves when font of paragraph changes", but then you almost have the answer in the title, right ?